# How to find what JS function is doing this?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-chrome-devtools

For study purposes i'm doing some tests with the web version of Whatsapp (https://web.whatsapp.com/). I found out that when i type an emoji shortcut in the text box, the app will automatically change it to the correspondent emoji. For instance, if i type

(y)

It will be replaced by

[image]

What i'm trying to learn to improve my JS skils is : how to find out what function is doing this and and how can i  manually call the function.

I tried to find it on Devtools but could not suceed.

Any ideas ?

Thanks

Comment: Most likely, their javascript is [Minified](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minification_(programming)) and cannot easily be read

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am answering your question about figuring out what might have caused a DOM change.  I am not answering your derivative question about what is **actually** causing the change.

Leverage the browser's devtools.  You have the ability to break on changes to a DOM element.  You have tagged [[image]google-chrome-devtools](/questions/tagged/google-chrome-devtools) so going with that example:

1. Navigate to the "Elements" panel
2. Right click on the element you want to monitor
3. Click "break on → subtree modifications"
4. Trigger the change
5. You will then be in the "Sources" panel with an active breakpoint on whatever code caused the modificiation
6. From there, navigate the call stack until you find the function at whatever level you are looking for

[image: DOM breakpoint]

Comment: Thank you, i did not know about this feature. I really appreciate your time in helping me. Have a nice day :)